# How to call memory in latex using any kind of use package?

Tags: packages

When I am writing in LaTeX sometimes it happens that I have to use a single word like `neutrino` and it may come several times in my report. Can you suggest me any package which, if I write say `ne` then from memory it will suggest me that it means "neutrino" like in Microsoft office.

Comment: If you are using Emacs you may try the predictive mode http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode

Comment: This depends on the editor's facilities; no LaTeX package can influence the way you type the document.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set up a macro and then use it to recall the whole word.  For example:

```
\newcommand{\ne}{neutrino}
```

and then every time you type `\ne{}` you'll get the word `neutrino` in your output.

Or, as mentioned by daleif, you can also use the `xspace` [package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) and then write:

```
\newcommand{\ne}{neutrino\xspace}
```

so you just need to type `\ne` to get `neutrino` with the proper spacing without the need of the `{}` after `\ne`

Comment: add `xspace` and `\xspace` that helps. Though I'd rather that the OP wrote *newtrino* having short cuts all over the source makes it a lot harder to read.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @daleif, it's actually very helpful